# How to fix Connection Issue or Update Needed on Ollama

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ollama

I'm getting a "Ollama Version: Not Detected" and a "Open WebUI: Server Connection Error" after installing Webui on ubuntu with:

`sudo docker run -d -p 3000:8080 -e OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL=http://host.docker.internal:11434/api --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -v open-webui:/app/backend/data --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main`

Going on Settings > General > Ollama api url I have: http://localhost:11434/api

Running `Ollama serve` gives me:

`Error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:11434: bind: address already in use`

Going to http://127.0.0.1:11434/ I get presented with: `Ollama is running`
Going to http://localhost:11434/api gives me: `404 not found`
But going to http://localhost:11434/api/version gives me: `version:    "0.1.25"`
I also did `sudo ufw disable` to make sure it wasn't a firewall issue

I've tried this: https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/faq.md#setting-environment-variables-on-linux
And doing `sudo systemctl edit ollama.service` gives me a file, like this:

```
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/ollama.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Unit]
Environment="OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0:11434"
Environment="OLLAMA_ORIGINS=*"

### Lines below this comment will be discarded

### /etc/systemd/system/ollama.service
# [Unit]
# Description=Ollama Service
# After=network-online.target
# 
# [Service]
# ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ollama serve
# User=ollama
# Group=ollama
# Restart=always
# RestartSec=3
# Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin"
# 
# [Install]
# WantedBy=default.target
```

I've tried also doing:

```
sudo docker stop open-webui
sudo docker rm -f open-webui
#variations of the install command
```

If I use curl:

different device on same network curl  `curl http://192.168.y.x:11434/api`:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.y.x port 11434: Connection refused`

same device curl `curl http://192.168.y.x:11434/api`
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.y.x port 11434 after 0 ms: Connection refused`

same device curl `curl http://127.0.0.1:11434/api`
`404 page not found`

Curl  inside docker `docker exec -it open-webui sh`:

`curl http://192.168.y.x:11434/api` -> `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.y.x port 11434 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`
`curl http://127.0.0.1:11434/api` -> `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 11434 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`
`curl http://host.docker.internal/api` ->

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at host.docker.internal Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Can someone tell me what do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if I have got the wrong end of the stick. I don't know much about this.

I gather that you are running Ollama on your host machine and you are trying to access it on port 11434 at `host.docker.internal`, which is a Docker Desktop feature I believe. I don't use Docker Desktop. However, if the goal is just to get this working then you can start by using Docker host network.

```
docker run --rm \
  -e OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:11434/api \
  --add-host=127.0.0.1:host-gateway \
  --net=host \
  --name open-webui \
  ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main
```

The `--net=host` will mean that the UI process will be able to access Ollama directly at 127.0.0.1:11434 on the host. Presumably this is what you are trying to do via `host.docker.internal` in Docker Desktop.

Then visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/.

Perhaps using Docker Compose would work well, with Ollama running in one service and the UI in another?

[image]

Adding in more options from the original question:

```
docker run \
  -e OLLAMA_API_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:11434/api \
  --add-host=127.0.0.1:host-gateway \
  --net=host \
  --name open-webui \
  -v open-webui:/app/backend/data \
  --restart always \
  ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main
```

The `--rm` option has been removed since it is mutually exclusive with `--restart always`.

To install and start Ollama on Linux you'd do something like:

```
curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
```

It will download and install, then start the Ollama server.

Comment: I have one issue before I can mark this as answered. The command is missing: `-v open-webui:/app/backend/data \ --name open-webui \ --restart always`

Comment: No problem. Updated with those missing arguments.